# Angular2 Exception: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular

Obviously the beta for Angular2 is newer than new, so there's not much information out there, but I am trying to do what I think is some fairly basic routing.

Hacking about with the quick-start code and other snippets from the https://angular.io website has resulted in the following file structure:

```
angular-testapp/
    app/
        app.component.ts
        boot.ts
        routing-test.component.ts
    index.html
```

With the files being populated as follows:

**index.html**

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

**boot.ts**

```js
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {RoutingTestComponent} from './routing-test.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Component Router</h1>
        <a [routerLink]="['RoutingTest']">Routing Test</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/routing-test', name: 'RoutingTest', component: RoutingTestComponent, useAsDefault: true},
])

export class AppComponent { }
```

**routing-test.component.ts**

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    template: `
        <h2>Routing Test</h2>
        <p>Interesting stuff goes here!</p>
        `
})
export class RoutingTestComponent { }
```

Attempting to run this code produces the error:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property ("
        <h1>Component Router</h1>
        <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['RoutingTest']">Routing Test</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        "): AppComponent@2:11
```

I found a vaguely related issue here; [router-link directives broken after upgrading to angular2.0.0-beta.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304115/router-link-directives-broken-after-upgrading-to-angular2-0-0-beta-0). However, the "working example" in one of the answers is based on pre-beta code - which may well still work, but I would like to know why the code I have created is not working.

Any pointers would be gratefully received!

Comment: The other question has something different : `directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]`.

Comment: I am getting the same error even with ROUTER_DIRECTIVES.
`@Component({selector: "app"}) @View({templateUrl: "app.html", directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink]})`

Comment: With the addition of `directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]` and changing from [router-link] to [routerLink] I am no longer getting the error.

Comment: I was getting the same error (NG8002: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'). I did not use the cli while creating the component. I forgot to add the component declaration in my module. Adding the component names in the declaration array fixed it for me.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

**>=RC.5**

import the `RouterModule`
See also https://angular.io/guide/router

```ts
@NgModule({ 
  imports: [RouterModule],
  ...
})
```

**>=RC.2**

**app.routes.ts**

```ts
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  ...
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [provideRouter(routes)];
```

**main.ts**

```ts
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

**<=RC.1**

Your code is missing

```ts
  @Component({
    ...
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    ...)}
```

You can't use directives like `routerLink` or `router-outlet` without making them known to your component.

While directive names were changed to be case-sensitive in Angular2, elements still use `-` in the name like `<router-outlet>` to be compatible with the web-components spec which require a `-` in the name of custom elements.

**register globally**

To make `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` globally available, add this provider to `bootstrap(...)`:

```ts
provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES], multi: true})
```

then it's no longer necessary to add `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` to each component.

Comment: yes you can assign multiple directives too at the time of bootstraping your app like this :- `provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, ETC...], multi: true})`

Comment: That's right, but `FORM_DIRECTIVES` are included in `PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES` by default already.

Comment: This was great, thanks. I also found this useful when trying to put it all together: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391790/globally-register-a-directive-in-angular2

Comment: RC means release candidate and is used for versions between beta and final release. 2.0.0-RC5 contained some substantial changes, but shortly after that 2.0.0 was released and then things remained stable. Versions before RC.5 didn't have `NgModule`.

Comment: This answer is quite old so I am scared..should I be?

Comment: @AlexanderMills why do old andwers scare you? Old answers are battle-tested and therefore very trustworthy ;p

Answer (score 117):

For people who find this when attempting to run tests because via `npm test` or `ng test` using Karma or whatever else. Your .spec module needs a special router testing import to be able to build.

```js
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [RouterTestingModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
});
```

http://www.kirjai.com/ng2-component-testing-routerlink-routeroutlet/

Comment: This is a great catch! My project wasn't having any problem with normal operation, it was in the `spec` file that I had to add this. Thanks @raykrow!

Comment: Confirmed to work in angular 4 as well.  Thanks for this!

Comment: This must be the accepted answer, the accepted answer is wrong, because when importing `RouterModule`, then you need to call `forRoot` to satisfy the module and then you should provide the `BASE_HREF` and ...

Comment: Do you have any idea if this is different for Angular 5+? I am getting the similar error `Can't bind to 'active' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.` in several of my unit tests, and have imported `RouterTestingModule`.

Answer (score 25):

**Word of caution when coding with Visual Studio (2013)**

I have wasted 4 to 5 hours trying to debug this error. I tried all the solutions that I found on StackOverflow by the letter and I still got this error: `Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known native property`

Be aware, Visual Studio has the nasty habit of autoformatting text when you copy/paste code. I always got a small instantaneous adjustment from VS13 (camel case disappears).

This:

```html
<div>
    <a [routerLink]="['/catalog']">Catalog</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/summary']">Summary</a>
</div>
```

Becomes:

```html
<div>
    <a [routerlink]="['/catalog']">Catalog</a>
    <a [routerlink]="['/summary']">Summary</a>
</div>
```

It's a small difference, but enough to trigger the error. The ugliest part is that this small difference just kept avoiding my attention every time I copied and pasted. By sheer chance, I saw this small difference and solved it.

Comment: Thank you, you could have mentioned the difference in case between "routerlink" vs "routerLink". Angular 2 expects "routerLink" to be present but finds "routerlink"

Comment: Thank you, for some reason, some tutorial used "router-link" with dash in between. But routerLink is the correct version.

Comment: The same happens with webpack and html-minifier, but only in production. add caseSensitive: true to the html-loader options see: github.com/SamanthaAdrichem/webpack-3.9.1-splitted-config-an‌​gular for a working angular 5 + webpack 3.9 config

Answer (score 13):

**For >= V5**

```js
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path:'routing-test', component: RoutingTestComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    // other imports here
    ]
})
```

component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Component Router</h1>
        <a routerLink="/routing-test" routerLinkActive="active">Routing Test</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `
})
```

**For < V5**

Also can use `RouterLink` as a `directives` ie. `directives: [RouterLink]`. that worked for me

```js
import {Router, RouteParams, RouterLink} from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [RouterLink],
    template: `
        <h1>Component Router</h1>
        <a [routerLink]="['RoutingTest']">Routing Test</a>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/routing-test', name: 'RoutingTest', component: RoutingTestComponent, useAsDefault: true},
])
```

Comment: I don't think this applies anymore (Angular 5) etc.

Answer (score 11):

In general, whenever you get an error like `Can't bind to 'xxx' since it isn't a known native property`, the most likely cause is forgetting to specify a component or a directive (or a constant that contains the component or the directive) in the `directives` metadata array.  Such is the case here.

Since you did not specify `RouterLink` or the constant `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` – which [contains the following](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/router/index.ts#L31-L31):

```
export const ROUTER_DIRECTIVES = [RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterLinkWithHref, 
  RouterLinkActive];
```

– in the `directives` array, then when Angular parses

```
<a [routerLink]="['RoutingTest']">Routing Test</a>
```

it doesn't know about the [RouterLink directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html) (which uses *attribute* selector `routerLink`). Since Angular does know what the `a` element is, it assumes that `[routerLink]="..."` is a *property* binding for the `a` element.  But it then discovers that `routerLink` is not a native property of `a` elements, hence it throws the exception about the unknown property.

---

I've never really liked the [ambiguity of the syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422820/why-does-simply-myhighlight-work-for-an-attribute-directive).  I.e., consider

```
<something [whatIsThis]="..." ...>
```

Just by looking at the HTML we can't tell if `whatIsThis` is

- a native property of `something`
- a directive's attribute selector
- a input property of `something`

We have to know which `directives: [...]` are specified in the component's/directive's metadata in order to mentally interpret the HTML.  And when we forget to put something into the `directives` array, I feel this ambiguity  makes it a bit harder to debug.

Answer (score 7):

You have in your module

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
```

you have to export the module RouteModule

example:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

to be able to access the functionalities for all who import this module.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried all methods, which are mentioned above.But no one method works for me.finally i got solution for above issue and it is working for me.

I tried this method:

In Html:

```
<li><a (click)= "aboutPageLoad()"  routerLinkActive="active">About</a></li>
```

In TS file:

```
aboutPageLoad() {
    this.router.navigate(['/about']);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I have imported the **RouterModule** in App module but not imported in my feature module. After import the router module in my EventModule the error goes away.

```js
    import {NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {EventListComponent} from './EventList.Component';
    import {EventThumbnailComponent} from './EventThumbnail.Component';
    import { EventService } from './shared/Event.Service'
    import {ToastrService} from '../shared/toastr.service';
    import {EventDetailsComponent} from './event-details/event.details.component';
    import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
    @NgModule({
      imports:[BrowserModule,RouterModule],
      declarations:[EventThumbnailComponent,EventListComponent,EventDetailsComponent],
      exports: [EventThumbnailComponent,EventListComponent,EventDetailsComponent],
       providers: [EventService,ToastrService]
    })
    export class EventModule {
        
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

If getting this error while unit testing please write this.

```js
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [RouterTestingModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
  });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate @raykrow's answer when one has this problem only in a test file! That is where I encountered it.

As it is often helpful to have another way to do something as a backup, I wanted to mention this technique that also works (instead of importing `RouterTestingModule`):

```
import { MockComponent } from 'ng2-mock-component';
. . .
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    MockComponent({
      selector: 'a',
      inputs: [ 'routerLink', 'routerLinkActiveOptions' ]
    }),
    . . .
  ]
```

(Typically, one would use `routerLink` on an `<a>` element but adjust the selector accordingly for other components.)

The second reason I wanted to mention this alternate solution is that, though it served me well in a number of spec files, I ran into a problem with it in one case:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
    More than one component matched on this element.
    Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
    Conflicting components: ButtonComponent,Mock
```

I could not quite figure out how this mock and my `ButtonComponent` were using the same selector, so searching for an alternate approach led me here to @raykrow's solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use shared modules, just add RouterModule to a Module where your component is declared and don't forget to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Referenced from here [RouterLink does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832851/routerlink-does-not-work)

Answer (score -4):

My solution is simple. I am using [href] instead of [routerLink]. I have tried all solutions for [routerLink]. None of them works in my case.

Here is my solution:

```
<a [href]="getPlanUrl()" target="_blank">My Plan Name</a>
```

Then write the `getPlanUrl` function in the TS file.