# Globally register a directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I am developing an Angular application. I need to add special behavior to all links. In AngularJS would just write a directive like this:

```
angular.module('whatever.module', []).directive('href', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // do stuff
        }
    };
});
```

In Angular I can write a directive like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[href]',
})

export class MyHrefDirective {
    constructor() {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

But how can I tell the application to use that directive globally? I have a ton of views with links on them. Do I have to import it and specify it in the `directives` array in every of those components (which is A LOT)?

I tried injecting it to the `bootstrap` function like you're supposed to do with services to have one instance globally but **that didn't work**

Comment: i think if you provide your directive globaly i mean at the time of Bootstraping root component then no need to import in the array of every commponent

Comment: If you've read the last sentence in my question, you'd have known that i have already tried that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My understanding is that you have to opt in to all custom directives at the component level. Only PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES are implicitly included (ngFor, ngIf etc.).

However, you can register your own custom directive as a PLATFORM_DIRECTIVE

```
import { provide, PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/core';

bootstrap(RootCmp, [
  provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: YourCustomDirective, multi: true}),
]);
```

Here is an article that talks more about the process: 
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html

EDIT:
I consider this less of a concern now since components are declared at the module level. This means a lot less repetition since you no longer have to declare child components at the individual component level.

Comment: Thank you. That's an excellent answear, I was not aware of that. Works like a charm.

Comment: Note: That any `<XYZ>_PROVIDERS` like `HTTP_PROVIDERS` can be directly passed to list whereas all directives have to be passed in using `provide(..)` as explained above perfectly by TGH. It need not be a custom directive but even external npm library based directives, like directives from material2 library have to be passed into bootstrap function  this way.

Comment: Might want to update this answer since it's no longer relephant

Comment: Any ideea how it can be done in the latest version of Angular2? Just declaring it in the main module doesnt seem to do the trick and the 2 imports seem depricated.

Comment: is it still true for Angular v2.4.x?

Comment: that imports are deprecated in latests versions of angular, how can it be achieved?