# How can a directive be globally registered, so it applies to all Components used in the application

Tags: angular, autofill

**Background:**
We want to disable the autocomplete for all inputs in our application. The way to go there is, to add `autocomplete="off"` to all form elements. However, since this might be easily forgotten, we want to create a directive which automatically takes care of that. To avoid having to declare it in each Module again and again, I want to register the directive globally for all components.

**What we have tried:**
We looked all over the web, and the only article closely matching is this one: [Globally register a directive in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391790/globally-register-a-directive-in-angular) however, he seems to be not working, because `import { provide, PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/core';` does not exist anymore.

Is there any solution to make directives apply automatically to all components?

Comment: You can't declare global UI components. You will have to import a module in each module using this UI component.

Comment: Regarding PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897005/angular-2-0-0-rc-2-how-to-migrate-platform-directives

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module, add your directive there and import that module anywhere:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [FormDirective],
  exports: [FormDirective]
})
export class DirectivesModule { }

====================================

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    DirectivesModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class OtherModule { }
```

Comment: yeah, that is kinda what I want to avoid :)

Comment: I believe that if you declare the directive in the appModule, it will be global.