# Why does simply [myHighlight]="..." work for an attribute directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

The `myHighlight` attribute directive in the [dev guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) uses the `myHighlight` name as both the attribute selector:

```
selector: '[myHighlight]',
```

and an input property:

```
@Input('myHighlight') highlightColor: string;
```

I find it odd/counterintuitive that we don't have to specify the selector attribute like this (although if we do write it this way, it still works):

```
<span myHighlight [myHighlight]="color">highlight me</span>
```

Instead, we only have to specify the input property, and we magically get the directive as well:

```
<span [myHighlight]="color">highlight me</span>
```

I don't like this "shortcut"/syntactic sugar/magic, since it looks like we're binding to the `myHighlight` property of the `span` element, rather than what is actually happening: we're binding to the `myHighlight` property of the `myHighlight` attribute directive.  So, just by looking at the HTML, we can't easily determine which element/component/directive the `myHighlight` property is bound to.

Why does it work this way?

Consider this HTML fragment:

```
<div [accessKey]="...">
```

Is `accessKey` an HTML element property or an attribute directive with an input property also named `accessKey`?  (FYI, `accessKey` is a valid HTML element property, so this example is not an attribute directive.)

Getting back to the highlight directive... if I change the input property name to `highlightColor`:

```
@Input() highlightColor: string;
```

Then I have to specify the attribute selector along with the property binding, which I find less ambiguous:

```
<span myHighlight [highlightColor]="color">highlight me</span>
```

So the "shortcut" only seems to work if the input property name matches the attribute selector.

**Update:** it seems [structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html) use the same trick/shortcut.  E.g.,

```
<p *ngIf="condition">
  text here
</p>
```

is equivalent to

```
<template [ngIf]="condition">  <--- binds input property ngIf to NgIf directive, not to template
  <p>
    text here
  </p>
</template>
```

I just don't like the mixing of property name and selector.

Comment: I just had a look at the docs. There is some subtle stuff going on there: "This @Input decorator adds metadata to the class that makes the highlightColor property available for property binding under the myHighlight alias". Also this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#why-input

Comment: It's just one of the possible [selectors](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/compiler/selector.ts#L15). You can use the one the better fits for you.

Comment: I think this [PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5914) can be related as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At [ng-conf 2016](https://www.ng-conf.org/#/), I talked to Alex Rickabaugh, one of the [Angular team members](https://angular.io/about/), about my concerns.  He pointed out that the syntax is ambiguous in other ways as well.  E.g., we discussed this syntax:

```
<my-comp [whatIsThis]="someProperty">
```

We can't tell from reading the HTML if `whatIsThis` is a directive with an input property of the same name, or if `whatIsThis` is an input property of the `my-comp` component.

I guess the bottom line is that with Angular 2 we can't simply look at the HTML to understand what kind of binding is happening.  We have to know about the directives and components the application uses.  Bummer.

Comment: For those wondering what happens if the component has an input property named the same way as the directive, then both the directive and the component will get the property value. Yep confusing.