# Angular2 passing data to click handler

Tags: angular, typescript, click, dom-events

I am not sure if I am phrasing all of this correctly; a lot has changed in Angular2.  I am trying to pass form data to a component's service.  I want to pass this data whenever the "Generate" button is clicked.  I am encapsulating the form data in an object, and want to pass that object to a service that's injected into the component.  The service performs all of the heavy lifting.  All the component really does is display the output.

**generator.component.ts**

```
export class Generator {
    passwords: string[]; // output array
    passwordsObj: Object = { // form data passed to service
        letters: "",
        numbers: "",
        symbols: "",
        amount: ""
    };
    constructor(gs: GeneratorService) {
        this.passwords = gs.generatePasswords(passwordsObj); // originally hard-coded, I want to now trigger this method when the "Generate" button is clicked
    }

    clicked(obj) {
        // handle the click event?
    }
}
```

I want the `generatePasswords` method to take the `passwordsObj` as an argument.  I know how to do that.  I just don't know how to trigger the service's `generatePasswords` method when the component's button is clicked.

**generator.component.html** snippet

```
<button type="submit" (click)="clicked(passwordsObj)">Generate</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `private` or `public` to create an initialize the `gs` member/property (see the [TypeScript Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#parameter-properties), section Parameter Properties for more information about that):

```
constructor(private gs: GeneratorService) {}
```

Then in your click event handler, simply call the service method and pass your `passwordsObj` as a parameter:

```
clicked() {
   this.passwords = this.gs.generatePasswords(this.passwordsObj);
}
```

Note that you do not need to pass `passwordsObj` to the event handler, since it is a property of the component, hence the `clicked()` method has access to it via the `this` object.

Comment: I have another question related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36109641/angular2-component-one-way-binding-or-input, but don't want to duplicate it (I can't comment on other questions yet).  I'm trying to bind user input like `<input (ngModel)="passwordsObj.letters">`, but it's not working.  I thought that would bind user input to the data source.  I don't want to use two way bindings (avoid `[(ngModel)]`).  Do I have to use `@Input` for that?

Comment: @daChi, you should create another question, but if you don't want two-way binding, you probably want `<input (input)="passwordsObj.letters = $event.target.value">`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
clicked() {
  this.passwords = gs.generatePasswords(this.passwordsObj);
}
```

with

```
<button type="submit" (click)="clicked()">Generate</button>
```