# Angular 2 routerLink With Semantic URL

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to build a `routerLink` on a list page.

I have a Route defined like so:

`{ path: '/brands/:brandId/regions', component: RegionListComponent }`

The end result link would look like this:

`<a href="/brands/100/regions">Brand Regions</a>`

I'm trying to figure out how to write the routerLink:

`<a [routerLink]="['/brands/?????'], ????">regions</a>`

The above link shows up in a table so the `brandId` would be based on an `ngFor` iteration.

The `????` are where I'm not sure quite what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a [routerLink]="['/brands/' + item.id + '/regions']">regions</a>
```

or

```
<a [routerLink]="['/brands', item.id, 'regions']">regions</a>
```

depending if the route segments are on different components or all on the root component.

Comment: Both give the following exception: 
`
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property ("
        <td>{{brand.name}}</td>
        <td>{{brand.description}}</td>
        <td><a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/brands, brand.id, regions']">regions</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
`

Comment: Sorry, forgot some quotes on the 2nd example. The error message doesn't seem to be related to how the Url is created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34317044/angular2-exception-cant-bind-to-routerlink-since-it-isnt-a-known-native-pro/34317846#34317846

Comment: Got it. I was missing the `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`