# Angular2 Router link not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

My router link works from the root component and the same link not working if I move the links to child component. The plunker code shows the working link and non working link. Thank you in advance. The below is the not working links.

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-menu',
    template: `
    <div>
    <a routerLink="/comp11" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a> | 
    <a routerLink="/comp12" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a> | 
    <a routerLink="/comp21" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a> | 
    <a routerLink="/comp22" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
  </div>
`,
})
export class AppLayout {}
```

[Plunker code with issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/vYmZyvqVYuk8o2U4vpT6?p=preview)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should import `RouterModule` in your AppLayoutModule so it looks as follows:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {AppLayout} from './layout.component';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule ],
    declarations: [ AppLayout ],
    exports: [ AppLayout ]
})

export class AppLayoutModule {}
```

Without it component didn't know what the `routerLink` is and do not compile it to correct `href` attributes.

Updated Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mb5qc0EijlsCPzSsUPoe?p=preview)

Comment: Hi @Marcin,  i am curious, RouterModule was imported in AppRoutingModule, it shall be visible to all other feature modules, so am i wrong?

Comment: @Howard, it is not visible because modules do not inherit access to components, providers, etc. of other modules. Thus what is imported by AppModule is not accessible/visible for AppLayoutModule.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for you answering. This confused me a lot. So if i have a third party module A which declares few `components`, u mean i cannot use them in any other feature modules if i just `import` this module A into root module? It's a bit weird, what if this module A requires a `forRoot` configuration? Do i have to `import` & `config` it in every feature module depends on it?

Comment: @Howard, yes, you have to import this third party module in every feature module that uses components from it, because there is no inheritance between them. There are several reasons of such an approach, first of all - due to the possibility of lazy loading - you can load the modules, with components necessary for it to work, and they do not have to be loaded in the root module. The other is that, every module should be implemented in such a way, that you are able to reuse it in the other app - other parent module, so it should be self-sufficient. I hope that it is more clear for you now.

Comment: You know what? You saved my weekend :-) I'm a little bit disappointed, that angular (>=4) does not seem to reckognise the missing `RouterModule` and silently just ignores the `routerLink` directives.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the routerlink to work, you must import the Router to the component where you are working

Example

```
Import {Component} from '@ angular / core';
Import {Router} from '@ angular / router';

@Component ({
Selector: 'my-menu',
template:
<Div>
<a [routerLink]=["/comp11"]> Crisis Center </a>
<a <routerLink]=["/comp12"]> Heroes </a>
<a [routerLink]=["/comp21"]> Heroes </a>
<a <routerLink]=["/comp22"]> Heroes </a>
</ Div>
,}) 
Export class AppLayout{}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this was a standalone component that was imported into a module then you could as well just add the RouterModule to the imports of your module. I for one like to have the module declarations in my own file so a solution here would be to have app-module.

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {AppLayoutModule} from '...'; <--could also be a component

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        AppLayoutModule,
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The only thing you must be sure of is that the RouterModule is imported into the module that uses the routerLink directive, either in the module file or the component file.

Answer (score 0):

`RouterModule` is helping the consuming component to compile `routerLink`(directive) into correct href attributes. You can solve this issue in two ways.

1. You should import `RouterModule` inside your `AppLayoutModule` and other child modules also as below:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppLayout } from './layout.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
      BrowserModule, 
      RouterModule 
    ],
    declarations: [AppLayout],
    exports: [AppLayout]
})

export class AppLayoutModule {}
```

2. Otherwise simply create `SharedModule` and import & export `RouterModule` inside SharedModule. Then import SharedModule inside your child modules(This is the best way). You can also add all of your dependent modules inside SharedModule

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```