# Angular 2/4 - routerLinkActive not working properly

Tags: angular, routerlink, routerlinkactive

I have a problem with my routerLinkActive.

Here is two Gifs to explain.

1. First problem: When i start the app, none of the routerLinkActive give the class active. But if i click on a different route, that finaly works.

[image]

2. When I click at first on the current route, the class isn't displayed.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" class="{{menuItem.class}}">
       <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
           <i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>
           <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the tree of my route. (in red the component called)

[image]

and my route code:

```
import ...

const routes : Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      }, ..., {
        path: 'challenges',
        component: ImageRankComponent
      }, {
        path: 'niveau',
        component: LevelComponent
      }, {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    }
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {}
```

and menuItem is:

```
this.menuItems = ROUTES.filter(menuItem => menuItem);
const ROUTES : RouteInfo[] = [{
    path: 'dashboard',
    title: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'dashboard',
    class: ''
}, {
    path: 'challenges',
    title: 'Tous les challenges',
    icon: 'dashboard',
    class: ''
},
{
    path: 'niveau',
    title: 'Niveau en ligne',
    icon: 'dashboard',
    class: ''
}]
```

Do you know what can be my problem?

**EDIT:**

I have tried:

absolute route. ie:

```
 path: '/home/dashboard'
```

with

```
<a [routerLink]="menuItem.path">
```

and

```
<a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
```

And the result is the same. Not working.

**EDIT2:**

adding:

[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" to:

```
<li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" routerLinkActive="active" class="{{menuItem.class}} " [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
```

doesnt resolve the problem.

**EDIT3:**

The extension Augury says me that routerLink is true for the good route. But the class isn't activated in the DOM.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT4:**

So, I have done some exploration.

I have found that if I put my menuComponent (sidebar) in the parent root, that is working, I the active class is displayed (**But I don't want to put it in the parent**)

[image: Moving the menu to the parent works.]

**EDIT5:**

I have done a plunker of the situation... And the plunker works... I dont get it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/7KMlY2

Comment: Can you show how you have configured your routes?

Comment: can you try `[routerLink]="[/menuItem.path]"`

Comment: try  routerLink="/menuItem.path"

Comment: I have edited my work.  /menuItem.path doesnt work.

Comment: Because you're applying the active class to an ancestor of the routerLink, you may need `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"` on the list item. [More here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive).

Comment: Thanks. But [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" doesnt resolve the problem :/ .

Comment: Try with `[routerLink]="'menuItem.path'"`

Comment: That doesnt work. It put menuItem.path as a string and not a variable. But thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<li routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
    <a>Home</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 13):

So I have spend lot of time on this problem.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19167

The thing is: That works with angular 2 but not angular 4.

I have found a hack for angular 4:

```
<li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems" [routerLinkActive]="" [ngClass]="rla.isActive?'active':''"  #rla="routerLinkActive"class="{{menuItem.class}}">
  <a [routerLink]="[menuItem.path]">
                <i class="material-icons">{{menuItem.icon}}</i>
                <p>{{menuItem.title}}</p>
            </a>
</li>
```

with:

```
[routerLinkActive]="" [ngClass]="rla.isActive?'active':''"  #rla="routerLinkActive"
```

**EDIT ANGULAR 5 :**

With Angular 5, the bug is gone!

Comment: Excuse me, but your answer is just a workaround. It has nothing to do with making routerLinkActive directive work.

Comment: @tishma This "hack" is working today. But it's still a hack.

Comment: @Wandrille can you tell me where i can read more about effecting class on  `el a` if `el b` meets some logic. (like your answer) I want to see more examples like that

Comment: `#rla="` what is that called?

Comment: @Omar ***#rla="*** this is a template reference variable. See here: 
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-

Comment: @Omar I haven't really understood what you are looking for. But take a look at : https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet

Answer (score 3):

For those using standalone component, remember to import `RouterLinkActive`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the HomeComponent is lazily loaded. You don't have to move your routes to root component. Just try to add the RouterModule to the root component.

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552619/angular2-router-link-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for you help but unfortunetly, that doesnt change the result.