# Bootstrap 4 navbar active backgroup color

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, navbar, ng-bootstrap

In a Bootstrap 3 navbar when a link is active, the link background color is changed to show that its the active link. This seems to be missing in Bootstrap 4. Is there a way to show this or do I need to override the active class?

The Bootstrap 3 navbar shown below. You can see the active home link is highlighted How do I show this in Bootstrap 4.

[image]

The angular 5 code below

```
  <div class="navbar-collapse" [ngbCollapse]="navbarCollapsed" id="navbarContent">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/home']" (click)="navbarCollapsed = true">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/page1']" (click)="navbarCollapsed = true">Page 1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try checking this issue if it works for you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172769/angular-2-4-routerlinkactive-not-working-properly

Comment: Simply add css like `.active { background:#4FA9DC; color:#000;}`

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma thanks but I am already on Angular 5. Also the link is showing as active. Its just the background color thats missing.

Comment: Yeah just checked, seems like bootstrap removed background-color styles for active class in navbar . You can use the @JavascriptHuppTechnologies answer

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies had to add the css as you said. If you want to add it as an aswer I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Ok adding at answer.

Comment: @BeesNees Added at answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 doesn't have css for active class.

So you have to add css by your self

Simply add css like

```
.active {
   background:#4FA9DC; color:#000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[routerLinkActive]` property defines the `css` class which will be appended to the element once it matches the defined route.

So in your case, the `active` class will be appended to the element. What you need to do is define a the active class in your css file, as @JavascriptHuppTechnologies suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `.active` class is being applied, but it **won't be visible** unless the Navbar has the `navbar-dark` or `navbar-light` classes which it used to determine the color of the `active` links...

- Use `navbar-dark` for a light/white links on darker backgrounds
- Use `navbar-light` for a dark/gray links on lighter backgrounds

Comment: I am using navbar-light. My question is on the background styling as shown in the screenshot. That is missing, but the active class is applied.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 doesn't apply a background so add custom CSS

Answer (score 0):

```html
<nav class="nav nav-pills">
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['your_path1']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">item1</a>
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['your_path2']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">item2</a>
  <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['your_path3']" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">item3</a>
</nav>
```

use nav-pills for background color and add the class 'active' for routerLinkActive